# Write data to a .DAT file with Pipe Delimiter in .NET Core 2.1 version

Tags: c#, delimiter, asp.net-core-2.1, streamwriter, filehelpers

I was using File Helpers .Net Framework. But when i started using .Net Core 2.1, File Helpers is not compatible. Can someone tell me an alternate was to write a pipe delimiter .Dat file.

```
Public class product()
{
public int number {get;set;}
public string name {get; set;}
}
```

I want to write a text file with extension .DAT like the below format

```
1|John
2|Andrew
3|Stephen
```

Let me know which is the best option to do this.

Comment: Version 4.0 of FileHelpers? Latest version I can see is 3.4.1 and is built as a DotNetStandard Library.

Comment: Not sure about the version. have edited though

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach: Override ToString() to write each class in the format you want:

```
public class product()
{
    public int number {get;set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{number}|{name}";
    }
}
```

Then if you have say an `IEnumerable<product>` called products:

```
File.WriteAllLines(myFileName, products.Select(p => p.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: i did try this. i have List<product> called products and i am tried to use File.WriteAllLines but i get an error "Cannot convert product[] to string[] when i used the code

File.WriteAllLines(FullFilepath, products.array());

Comment: Sorry, that's what I get for posting after I've been called to dinner :-) Updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

The last release of FileHelpers was 3.3.0 which was over a year ago.  There has been active development with 3.4.1 branch having a very recent commit https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers/tree/3.4.1

In terms of .NET Core support, I know that 2.0 has been retired so it may be worth popping over to their repo and asking the question about 2.1 via an issue as no one else seems to have done.

If you feel like ditching FileHelpers (and I love to use that library myself), then you can make use of the `ToString()` method mentioned above by @ericj and utilise a `products` class to bring it together:

```
public class products() : List<product>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, this.ToArray());
    }
}
```

This is code written here so untested but the theory of it should work.